# Prove that if $g \circ f$ is onto and $f$ is one-to-one, $g$ may still not be one-to-one.

Tags: functions

> Assume that $g \circ f$ is onto and $f$ is one-to-one. Prove that $g$ is not necessarily one-to-one.

I am unable to think of an example where $g$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: If $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=5$, then $f$ is 1-1 but $g$ is not. I suspect that some condition is missing from this problem statement.

Comment: What is $f$? What is $g$? Add some more context and an attempt or this will be removed.

Comment: You left off information.  Do you, perhaps, know something about one of the composed functions $f\circ g$ or $g\circ f$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $x \mapsto (x,0)$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $(x,y) \mapsto x$. $f$ is one-to-one, $g \circ f$ is the identity function on $\mathbb{R}$ so it is onto, but $g$ is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f ; X \mapsto Y$ be a bijection. Basicaly, any map $g : Y \mapsto Z$ that isn't a surjection will do the job.

e.g suppose $Y$ has at least $2$ elements, take $Z := \{x\}$ a singleton and consider the constant map $g$ defined by $g(y) = x$ for all $y \in Y$.
Clearly, $g \circ f$ is a surjection but $g$ is not a bijection.